Can not apply migration "column cannot be cast automatically to type bigint"
I am running a service locally with existing migrations. When applying one of the migrations, I get an error 'column cannot be cast automatically to type bigint.' What could be the issue if the service is currently working in production?
Migration was created with ef core 6
I use ef core 8
Migration:
 migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<long>(
                name: "external_id",
                table: "pickup_points",
                type: "bigint",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(string),
                oldType: "text");

If I change type to "bigint USING external_id::bigint" it works. Why does this happen?

This is expected - PostgreSQL refuses to just change column types when the conversion isn't guaranteed to be successful; for example, your old text column could contain non-numeric data. Note that if you converted the other way around (bigint -> text), you would not get this error.
